# How to get checkbox checked value from datagrid in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter, i am simple datagrid with few columns.... what i want from grid is...i need get checked values from grid,....so i dont know how use foreach loop and get the values..

can any one explain me with example plz....

```
 foreach ($persons as $person)
    {
        $this->table->add_row(form_checkbox('att',$person->tab_classid), $person->tab_classid, $person->tab_classtitle, date('d-m-Y H:i',strtotime($person->tab_classtime)),$person->tab_pemail,anchor($person->tab_prsturl,'view','target="_new"'),anchor($person->tab_recurl,'view','target="_new"'),$person->tab_classduration,$person->tab_crtdate, 
        anchor('person/view/'.$person->tab_classid,'view',array('class'=>'view')).' '.
        anchor('person/update/'.$person->tab_classid,'update',array('class'=>'update')).' '.
        anchor('person/test/'.$person->tab_classid,'Attendee',array('class'=>'attendee')).' '.
        anchor('person/delete/'.$person->tab_classid,'delete',array('class'=>'delete','onclick'=>"return confirm('Are you sure want to delete this person?')"))
        );
    }
    $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is best for processing server code but what you are looking for is tend to be of client side analyses. I suggest you do this sort of check by javascript/jquery instead.

Leave/process this in an `each(function(){...});`

```
var check=$('chkboxId').attr('checked').value;
```

Comment: Like how, can you give me example plz